# Facebook Connect Site Like Digg (PHP)

Tags: php, facebook, digg

I'm looking for a PHP tutorial or example of how to set up a facebook connect site like digg. Basically allowing local users to connect their facebook accounts to their local accounts indefinitely (until they opt out). This would then automatically reconnect them to facebook every time they log in with their local accounts.

I've been trying for a long time to find a complete start-to-finish tutorial. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook provides [extensive documentation](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Getting_Started_with_Facebook_Connect), including [the full source of a sample PHP website, "The Run Around"](http://svn.facebook.com/svnroot/platform/samples/therunaround/), that has all the necessary functionality.

There's lots of useful stuff, including [the exact steps that occur between Facebook, the browser, and your site](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/How_Connect_Authentication_Works) on the developer documentation wiki. Any specific questions you have after reading the docs?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I never came across "The Run Around", but this is what I needed.